# message box for spin ctrl event in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, messagebox

Hi all i am learning python and  wxpython ,now i am stuck while  doing spin-ctrl button event,

problem: I have a spin ctrl and few text_ctrl ,spin_ctrl max value is 7 and and it should not set it using max,min or setvalue(). when user goes to 8 or more i want to pop up a message saying that 7 is maximum. or if user enters 8 . i tried to bind it and bring up a message but it comes for each click.:(
thanks for your help and spending yo time for my issue in advance.
sorry if any mistakes found.

Comment: just bind its wx.EVT_CHANGE (i think) to a function that checks the value of the spin ....

Comment: @JoranBeasley:    Binding it to a EVT is not working ,i have checked it.

Comment: do you have a spin ctrl? or a text_ctrl with a spin_button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set your max to 8 so that you can get a big enough number and listen to EVT_TEXT

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Spin Button Tutorial")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.text = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value="1")
        self.text.SetRange(1, 8)
        self.text.SetValue(1)

        self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.OnSpin)
        self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnSpin)



    def OnSpin(self, event):
        if self.text.GetValue() > 7:
               self.text.SetValue(7)
               wx.MessageDialog(self,"Test Message","Too Big!").ShowModal()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: working proper , used message box instead of dailog :) thanks :)